# Syncfusion SfListView not selecting items

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, cross-platform, syncfusion

So I have this list I need to select items from, and I'm not able to get the selection feature to work, this is my code:

```
        <syncfusion2:SfListView SelectionMode="Multiple"
            SelectionGesture="Tap"
            x:Name="bandSch"
            SelectionBackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0.8,1,0.3"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            ItemSize="40"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local2:BandInfoRepository}, Path=BandInfo}">
            <syncfusion2:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5,0,5,5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding BandSchedule}"
                                TextColor="#00b5d1"
                                FontSize="12" 
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                WidthRequest="50"
                            />
                            <Button Text="Seleccionar"
                                FontSize="16"
                                TextColor="#00b5d1"
                                BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"
                                Margin="5"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                BorderRadius="14"

                            />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </syncfusion2:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        </syncfusion2:SfListView>
```

I'd love a little help with this, as I cannot get either single or multiple selection to work and I have no idea why.

Comment: What does "I'm not able to get the selection feature to work" mean? Does it not select any rows? Does it crash? Something else? We are not mind readers, so you need to provide some more information to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean it doesn't select any items when you tap the screen, I tried every gesture (hold, double tap and tap) but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling with this myself I discovered that it could be a combination of issues that would cause this.   In my scenario I had the code initialized within my iOS AppDelegate.cs file, but I had set a background color for the item in a data template.  It appears that if you set a background color on the item, then the selection action will not change the background.   This causes it to appear as if the selection is not operating correctly, when in fact it's just the background color isn't being changed on selection.   In my case I removed the item background and let the selection background change the background color at the time of selection.  This fixed my issues.

On the initialization of the renderer in the AppDelegate.cs I would like to mention that auto complete within Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition didn't help me much in finding the path to the import I needed to allow me to call the renderer's init function.   After about 30 minutes of frustration I found it in the following package.   Hope this saves someone else some time in the future.

Using statement at the top:

```
using Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.iOS;
```

What my FinishedLaunching looks like.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            // Call the INIT.
            SfListViewRenderer.Init();
            mainForms = new App();  
            LoadApplication(mainForms);

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reported issue “Selection events are not raised in SfListView” occurs due to SfListViewRenderer might not be initialized or render assemblies may not be added as reference in your renderer projects. So, we recommend to refer the following UG documentation link to initialize the SfListView renderer and assemblies need for each renderer projects to resolve the issue at the sample level.

**Launching SfListView in each platform:** https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/getting-started#launching-the-sflistview-on-each-platform

**Assemblies required for each platform:** https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/getting-started#sflistview-for-xamarinforms

Please let us know if you require further assistance.

Regards,
Dinesh Babu Yadav

Comment: They already are, and I followed every step on those links you shared.

Comment: Also, every property I use is working, it's just the selection that is not working right.